# "You know" in spoken English

Tags: writing-style, speech, filler-words

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use “you know”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7297/how-to-use-you-know)

Why is "you know" most commonly used in spoken English. Or to phrase it differently, why do native speakers use this expression a lot in spoken English? Is it a good way of speaking? Does it have to do anything with a particular country, culture, etc?

Comment: btw, "you know" is used as a filler in some other languages, too. What's your first language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most cases it's a space-filler with no meaning at all other than "er..."; or it means "well you *do* know, just give me a few moments to think of what it's called..."

> "Where are you going?"
>   "I'm going to the, you know, shopping mall."

Comment: That is true. It is, like, an abused phrase if I've ever, like, seen one. ;)

Comment: @shinyspoongod I know, right?

Comment: @cornbreadninja Shut up!!!! You are so, like, right. Innit?

Comment: We was talking at work and I was like, I wonder if I should mention *like*? And my friend was like, No, keep it simple.

Comment: I'd say this is frequently used to emphasize not exactly clear innuendos, metaphors, double-speak, hidden meanings etc. Like, in this example, it wouldn't be the shopping mall at all, but, you know, *the* "shopping mall".

Comment: Totally, man. Man, this is, like, heavy, you know?

Comment: "After a little while he got lost in a sea of commas. And they all lived sedated ever after."

Comment: "You know, I hate Mondays."

Comment: Are you having a laugh?

Answer (score 2):

It's a lazy/terse form of the expression, "do you know what I mean" or "do you know what I'm saying" which is not only informal, but is specifically used directly with the usually singular or small-group audience to make sure someone is following along in a conversation.

Answer (score 1):

"You know" can be included in the so-called *discourse particles*, that is those linguistic units of spoken language which have no real meaning, their function being merely a pragmatic one. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discourse_particle), they serve "to indicate the speaker's attitude, or to structure their relationship to other participants in a conversation."

As a personal note, I add that discourse particles, which are common in speech of every language in the world, may also reveal something about the mindset of a nation. E.g. English people are concerned about other people's understanding of what they say. Italians use "cioè," which means "that is," so they are perhaps more focused on finding a better way to say something or explaining their words.

Comment: Arabic has ‘ya’nee’ – it means.

Answer (score 0):

"You know" is used to imply that what is being referred to is known to or understood by the listener, or as a gap-filler in conversation.

> When in Rome, you know.

> I was, you know, wondering if you had news for me.