# Where can I find a list of common padding words?

Tags: word-usage, writing-style, lists, filler-words

Like a lot of people, I actually have the habit of actually adding a lot of actual padding words when I actually write. A common one I use is *actually*. These are actually rarely worth keeping, actually, and, when I actually remember, I actually make some actual effort to actually find and actually delete them all.

Is there a list of common padding words and terms that I can download?

This is partly out of curiosity, but partly for checking tools.

Comment: Related: [Garbage/Stuff words](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20424/garbage-stuff-words)

Comment: It should be noted that you can pack your writing with as many of these words as you like, but the editor will remove each and every one of them.

Comment: There was a study done not long ago about discourse markers.  They are apparently very important, not just for a speaker/writer to use, but also for the listeners/readers.  They help to organize the mind and to absorb the information.  Even non-words like "Uh" and "Um" work to the same effect.

Comment: @Phoenix - interesting, but I think my habit still overdoes it. That first paragraph is a *little* exaggerated, but...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some context dependent words can be found in [Tony1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User%3aTony1)'s [How to improve your writing, section "Eliminating redundancy"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User%3aTony1/How_to_improve_your_writing#Eliminating_redundancy):

- relatively
- still  (as in "While the journal had <strike>relatively</strike> low circulation numbers for its day, it <strike>still</strike> influenced popular opinion and was feared by the conservative administration.")

**Additive terms**

- also
- in addition
- moreover
- furthermore

**Temporal terms**

- over the years
- currently
- now
- from time to time
- to this day
- future (as in "They planned their <strike>future</strike> response".)

**Vague terms of size, number and proportion**

- some ("The highway expands to four lanes as it passes <strike>some</strike> built-up areas of strip development")
- a variety of
- a number of
- several
- a few
- many
- any ("The scheme does not remove <strike>any</strike> government-funded programs such as Social Security, Medicare and Medicaid")
- all

**Words for which the meaning is already conveyed in another word**

- its own ("Each weapon has <strike>its own</strike> advantages and disadvantages.")
- in those instances ("<strike>In those instances</strike> when requests for assistance fall outside Tahirih's scope, staff members attempt to locate other consultants.")
- subsequently
- who come

**Words for which the meaning is easily recoverable from the context or from general knowledge**

- Resulting ("The cigar smoker burns the dried leaves of the tobacco plant but does not inhale the <strike>resulting</strike> smoke")

---

See also *[Redundancy exercises: removing fluff from your writing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User%3aTony1/How_to_satisfy_Criterion_1a%3a_redundancy_exercises)*.

Answer (score 9):

These, I believe are called ["discourse markers"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discourse_marker). I can't find a list, but I can think of a list:

> Like
>   Well,
>   Ok,
>   Actually,
>   So 
>   You know,
>   oh, 
>   By the way,
>   Anyway,
>   Yeah no,
>   I mean
>   Now
>   Then
>   Frankly,
>   Also,
>   Basically,
>   As a matter of fact
>   In fact,

Comment: My colleague uses "The point is" all the time

Comment: That's another good one.

Comment: Great list. Basically.

Comment: I keep catching myself using "apparently." It's really annoying, even to myself...Curse you filler words!!!

Comment: My wife has gotten in the habit of prefacing *many* sentences with _"The thing about it is is"_.  Drives me insane.  There's no syntactically useful information there at all.

Answer (score 1):

[First to Know](http://firsttoknow.com/5-words-that-make-you-sound-stupid/?did=1179&utm_source=outbrain&utm_campaign=fivewords) gives a list of "Five Words that Make You Sound Stupid," adding insult to injury on these pointless discourse markers.  The article gives concise explanations of when it is actually appropriate to use these words.