# A word describing someone who says "like" or "um" every couple of words in most sentences

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, conversation

Is there a word (or a few words) that accurately describes someone with the "like disease" (or the many other unnecessary words or small phrases spread throughout most sentences, such as "um") in "proper" English?

I often find having a conversation which such a person very distracting, even annoying, and it makes it difficult to concentrate on the intent of their conversation when I constantly here like x, like y, like z, ...  if such a "word" describes this too, even better.

Comment: I call the person "Val".

Comment: Are such *fillers/filled pauses/hesitation markers/planners* really unnecessary? They communicate that the speaker is not finished speaking, but doesn't yet have the next word. Anyway, there may be a word for such a person, but since the behavior is so common, we tend to name the behavior, rather than the actor.  I.e. it's not worth labeling a group that comprises everyone who's ever spoken when nervous or unprepared.

Comment: They are ummers and errers.

Comment: @FXQuantTrader  I would get down-voted as neologisms are not allowed, considered off-topic :)

Comment: @juhasz  unnecessary ... yes?  At least in the case or "like" you don't think it's worth labelling them as an infectious group, particularly among younger English speakers 
 ...?  It really does seem to be a phenomenon that those around them often starting throwing likes about after communicating with each other frequently ...

Comment: @NigelJ Language Log has a great series starting on the [usage differences between um and uh/er](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=13581). With graphs! [More on UM and UH](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=13713)

Comment: This is just an um personal pet  peeve so that you can find an um pejorative term you can use against people you're um well like really peeved with. Don't be mean! It like violates our Be Like Nice policy.

Comment: No worries,  I was just teasing, like. Also, I'm actually an old guy. Professionally sound-edited radio interviews regularly delete these fill words that occur in everyone's natural speech.

Comment: Perhaps [*fluency impaired*](https://www.hopkinsmedicine.org/health/conditions-and-diseases/fluency-disorder)?

Comment: @jxh - Why?  They're quite fluent in ValleySpeak.

Comment: At the duplicate, the excessive use of fillers / crutch words is revealed as **'embolalia**'. [Nordquist, at ThoughtCo](https://www.thoughtco.com/embolalia-speech-term-1690644), even has an article.

Comment: The proper duplicate is: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/146441/87426

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments under the question about *like* being a deliberately stylistic form of speech aside, if somebody is constantly struggling for words, where things like *um*, *uh*, or *ah* (essentially, meaningless filler sounds) are frequently repeated as they try to think of how to express themselves next, that person would be said to be [**tongue-tied**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tongue-tied):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **1** : unable or disinclined to speak freely (as from shyness)

---

However, if they don't seem to be struggling for what to say next, but are simply using such sounds as actual parts of their speech, they could simply be said to be [**ineloquent**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ineloquent):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   : not eloquent : having or showing a lack of eloquence
>   // George W. Bush, often so *ineloquent* in public, worked hard as governor of Texas and afterward to master legislative arguments and complications.
>   — James Fallows, The Atlantic, "Trump's Latest Interview Highlights Four of His Greatest Flaws," 20 July 2017