# What do you call superfluous filler words like 'So' 'Anyhow' 'Anyway'?

Tags: filler-words

Examples:

> *Anyway*, after that I went home and went to sleep.
>
> *Anyhow*, do you want to go for a drink?
>
> *So then*, I was chatting to this girl and...
>
> *Now*, Bob was a nice guy, but socially inept.
>
> Her cooking was, *well*, terrible.

These words are distinct from fillers like 'umm' and 'err' because they are often used intentionally in written, usually informal, English, such as writing expressing a conversational tone.

Comment: ***Filler Words***: http://grammar.about.com/od/fh/g/fillerterm.htm

Comment: From the sentences you are showing they just look like 'adverbs'.  ***Anyway***: (adverb) used to indicate that a statement explains or supports a previous statement;  *"Anyhow, he is dead now"; "I think they're asleep; anyhow, they're quiet"; "I don't know what happened to it; anyway, it's gone"; "anyway, there is another factor to consider"; "I don't know how it started; in any case, there was a brief scuffle"; "in any event, the government faced a serious protest"; "but at any rate he got a knighthood for it"* http://www.thefreedictionary.com/anyway

Comment: I'll just point out  that [this question here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24633/what-makes-like-and-so-popular?rq=1) addresses this question quite well.

Answer (score 2):

Insofar as the 'superfluous filler words' denote or relate to language used for general purposes of social interaction, rather than to convey information or ask questions, they are *phatic*.

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/phatic