# How to use "if you will" in third person

Tags: word-choice, pronouns, third-person

How would one say "if you will" in third person POV?

I'm constantly finding myself wanting to type this phrase in papers but I usually refrain from it since "you" is second person and my teachers are exceptionally strict when it comes to POV in research papers.

Normally, I just replace "you" with "one" but that doesn't sound very... smooth, if you will.

Comment: This seems like a casual phrase that I wouldn't even use in a paper.

Comment: Two people telling me not to use this phrase is good enough for me. I had a feeling that was the answer. Thanks!

P.S. Do you mind posting that as an answer @BillFranke so I can accept it?

Comment: posted comment as answer.

Comment: Case closed, I see; but still I'm curious what you were trying to do. The phrase "If you will" is meant to address the reader of the paper - I mean, you _are_ talking about use cases such as "we did a lot of research, or 'googling' if you will", right? So who are you addressing if you write it in the third person?

Comment: About the closest I can think of is "one might say". It's not a real answer as it's just a phatic expression that happens to use the third person, and if anything is even worse in weakening the overall expression (of course you might say it, you just did).

Comment: The reason I wanted to use this phrase was because I used a term that isn't necessarily a technical term and I wanted to make that clear, but now that I think about it, i should just use  technical term to be more accurate, anyways.

Comment: @Brandon Maybe you can qualify that with "in layman's terms" or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to use this pleonastic phrase? What does it add to the research paper beyond a verbal tic? **Eliminate all unnecessary words!** These words are absolutely unnecessary. I've been editing academic research papers every day for the past 16 years, and I've never yet seen one with this phrase. It's strictly a phatic remark reserved for spoken English and dialogue. See [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77790/what-does-if-you-will-mean) and [this](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=3239).