# Phenomenon of overused and popular words

Tags: word-choice, phrases, filler-words

Certain words or phrases become really popular. These words are picked up by many people, are overused, and sometimes misused to such an extent that the whole meaning of the word changes, or is even lost. I would describe these words as fads, because they become popular, but then (usually) disappear again.

Two examples:

- Like: This morning I was, like totally, late for work.
- Literally: If I do not get my phone back, I will literally die of boredom.

What is that phenomenon called? Is there a definition of what I just described?

**Edit:** After reading all the comments and responses I realized that my question was confusing. I was looking for a word that describes the phenomenon of (initially odd usages of) words being picked up and used by other people.

I gave the examples and stated what happens to these words to clarify what I meant.

Comment: If you're looking for a word to describe the overuse itself, try [*trite*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/trite). If you're looking to describe why this happens to certain words but not others, I'm not sure how to label that catchiness.

Comment: @J.R.: ...um...submit 'trite' and 'catchy' as an answer?

Comment: I think _fad word_ is just about perfect for _words_ that shift in meaning temporarily. Temporary changes in dialect etc. would simply be a _fad_ or an _affectation_.

Comment: _Literally_ has been used this way for some 250 years, and the usage shows no signs of dying out.

Comment: @coleopterist: The problem is, words do change meaning, and it is not inconceivable that *literally* could come to mean something less absolute than it currently does — and stay that way.

Comment: @Robusto I was thinking of words that revert back to the original meaning. For example, apparently kids in the UK are/were in the habit of saying "[That is so book](http://wordlily.com/2007/06/23/book-cool/)" where _book=cool_. If it hasn't already, I expect that this practice will die out soon and _book_ will retain its original meaning. How would this *temporary* practice be classified? (I realise that this is something of a narrow example. I'll try to come up with a more mainstream one.)

Comment: @coleopterist, Do you know that when phones first used predictive text, that the phone would often guess "book" when you typed "cool." I heard a comedian do a bit using the words that his phone guessed he meant, and one of the sentences was, "That is so book."

Comment: @JLG Yep. I've linked to a random blog in my comment with a similar explanation. But I thought that it was a recent fad. Quite amusing, at any rate :)

Comment: You'd think librarians would get some mileage out of book=cool.

Comment: Funny that you say they use "book" to mean "cool". I suspect you mean they use "book" to mean "trendy", "fashionable", or perhaps simply "good", and not "low temperature". "Cool" is itself a word that has acquired the slang meaning of "good". Of course, we have about 637 slang terms that mean "good", and most of them come and go with each generation of teenagers.

Comment: Here's the comedian's bit [I referred to.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g4PXkAduiv0)

Comment: You have defined cliché, as the current top answer points out. But your examples are not clichés - they are, respectively, two filler words and an intensifier. They both happen to be frowned upon by certain language peevers, but that's not a function of overuse, faddishness, or "loss" of meaning. No one is going around wondering what the sentence "He was totally literal at all times, like a robot" means because "totally," "literal," and "like" also happen to be used in ways that irritate pedants.

Comment: @JLG, and for those at work, [here's the transcript](http://www.livedash.com/transcript/arj_barker__lyao/6732/COMEDYP/Saturday_January_23_2010/174163/), starting at 00:26:50

Comment: @Evan Harper: So they're in the general class of pedant markers?

Comment: I'm closing this because, as should be clear from the comments and the answers so far, this question is rather poorly defined. For what it's worth, we have half a dozen questions specifically dedicated to the [Valley-Girl *like*](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/1531/), and we have a question dedicated to [*literally*](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/1863/). Check them out and you will see for yourself that a) they are two completely different beasts and b) "overused" is in the eye of the beholder. No wonder the answers here are all over the map.

Comment: @RegDwighт Exactly what I felt about the question. We have already beaten this idea to death, so to speak.

Answer (score 20):

What you describe is actually the definition of *cliché.*

From the [Wikipedia article:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clich%C3%A9)

> A *cliché* or *cliche** (UK /ˈkliːʃeɪ/ or US /klɪˈʃeɪ/) is an expression, idea, or element of an artistic work which has been **overused to the point of losing its original meaning or effect, especially when at some earlier time it was considered meaningful or novel**. ... 
>   Most phrases now considered clichéd were originally regarded as striking, but lost their force through overuse.

Comment: I would like totally not consider such use of the word _like_ to be clichéd :) Is it?

Comment: I think so. What traditional definition of "like" would you say describes how the word is used by younger people today? Now there is the [added definition of:](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&sugexp=les%3B&gs_nf=1&cp=7&gs_id=1z&xhr=t&q=like+definition&pf=p&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=like+de&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=9e7384346162f6f2&biw=1348&bih=550) "Used in speech as a meaningless filler or to signify the speaker's uncertainty about an expression just used."

Comment: According to the source of that definition, it is being used as an adverb. It's a filler, a hedge, or a dialectal affectation. While _fad_ could collectively represent both words and such affectations due to their possible ephemerality, IMO, the question, by virtue of the two examples provided, is talking about two different things rather than one. Words can be clichéd, as can phrases, but I don't think verbal tics, fillers, dialectal peculiarities etc. can be on an individual basis.

Comment: In constructions such as "And he's like, 'Radical!' ", _be like_ has been classed by at least one grammar as a recent multi-word quote verb.

Comment: That's why Shakespeare was such a bad writer - his work is nothing but cliches

Comment: "A meaningless filler to signify..." is so deliciously self-contradictory.

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps the word you're looking for is **[Meme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meme)**.

"An idea, behavior or style that spreads from person to person within a culture"

Memes encompass a lot more than individual words, and I think *fad word* may also be useful if you're trying to be specific about individual words - but a fad word is a type of meme.

Comment: +1 and to the @JLG answer, the examples sound like *memes* sliding into *cliches*.

Comment: I think 'meme' is too general to be of use here. As you point out, memes can be lots of things. And while the OP's examples are indeed memes, the term is used for a lot of things which are completely unrelated to what the OP was talking about.

Answer (score 8):

The official term for this is either [*semantic change, semantic shift, or semantic progression*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_change):

From the linked article (emphasis my own):

> Semantic change, also known as semantic shift or semantic progression describes the evolution of word usage — **usually to the point that the modern meaning is radically different from the original usage**. In diachronic (or historical) linguistics, semantic change is a change in one of the meanings of a word. Every word has a variety of senses and connotations, which can be added, removed, or altered over time, often to the extent that cognates across space and time have very different meanings. The study of semantic change can be seen as part of etymology, onomasiology, semasiology, and semantics.

Comment: "Semantic drift" is another synonym for this.

Comment: Is the use of a hedge such as _like_ considered a _semantic shift_? The OP mentions that fads usually tend to disappear over time; are there temporary semantic shifts?

Comment: All shifts are in some sense temporary. Languages continue to evolve.

Answer (score 5):

If you're talking about faddish clichés, it sounds like what you're looking for here is a ***hackneyed refrain***.

The OED definition of *hackneyed* is:

> Used so frequently and indiscriminately as to have lost its freshness and interest; made trite and commonplace; stale.

Answer (score 3):

Clichés and memes have been mentioned, but really, the [snowclone](http://spectrum.ieee.org/at-work/education/snowclone-is-the-new-clich) is the new cliché.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowclone) says “A snowclone is a neologism for a type of cliché and phrasal template originally defined as ‘a multi-use, customizable, instantly recognizable, time-worn, quoted or misquoted phrase or sentence that can be used in an entirely open array of different variants’”, and mentions (eg) “comedy is the new rock ’n’ roll” and ”grey is the new black” as snowclones of the form ”X is the new Y”.

I suspect many fad (or [vogue](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vogue#Noun), [trendy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/trendy#Adjective), [rage](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rage#Noun)) words arise or are [coined](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/coin#Verb) via [argot](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/argot#Noun), [cant](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cant#Noun), or [jargon](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jargon#Noun), and meet the needs or desires of [youth voice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Youth_voice) advocates, the [youth subculture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Youth_subculture), or of one in-crowd or another.

Answer (score 2):

A [**catchphrase**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catchphrase) (or **catch-phrase**) is a phrase or expression recognized by its repeated utterance. --*Wikipedia*

[**catch·phrase**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/catchphrase): a word or expression that is used repeatedly and conveniently to represent or characterize a person, group, idea, or point of view --*merriam-webster*

**[catchphrase](http://grammar.about.com/od/c/g/catchphraseterm.htm)** A vogue expression, often media-inspired and usually short-lived.  --grammar.about.com

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between misusing a word because you don't understand its meaning, and using it ironically. "I am literally going to die" is an ironic use of "literally." The complaint about pedants not liking that use of "literally" is a bogus attack on supposedly hypercritical language lovers, who really wouldn't mind most casual use of such phrases -- but who do object to the sly misuse of "pedant" to suggest "asshole."

Comment: Hi David. I think you are saying that this phenomenon is attributable to ironic usage, but your answer doesn't clearly address the question and comes across as a little tangential.  You might want to edit it to make it clearer.